# Como usar a API do Google analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Os exemplos, o registro no Google Developers Console, achei tudo muito enrolado.

Como criar um Hello Analytics de forma "simples" em PHP?

Comment: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/pegando-dados-do-google-analytics-via-php/

Comment: Obrigado pelo link, porém esse método não funciona mais.

Comment: Como não testei, preferi apenas comentar e não postar uma resposta. Boa sorte.

Comment: Documentação do _goog_ geralmente é péssima. Cheia de erros, e sempre desatualizada. Pra implementar uma solução Single Sign On perdi horas e horas. Agora está uma belezinha, mas só funciona por eu ter pesquisado outras soluções que já funcionavam. A api PHP (ao menos a 1.3.1, que eu vi) até que é boa, nem parece deles. Aprendi a usar um pouco olhando o fonte e a pasta de exemplos, pra complementar os limites da documentação.

Comment: Link pra API em PHP: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o mesmo problema dessa forma:

No Console, você precisa criar uma autorização para o OAuth e para o Public API Access.

Ambos devem solicitar acesso a partir do `http://localhost`, se você estiver acessando localmente.

Caso você tenha publicado o seu código, você precisa digitar a URL.

Depois disso, você pega o clientId do OAuth e a apiKey do Public API Access.

Pronto, de posse desses códigos você vai conseguir.